# add 'on update' & 'on delete' foreign key constraints with laravel migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making my table like this...

```
    Schema::create('matched_merchants', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('merchant_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('offer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('merchant_id')->references('id')->on('merchants')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->foreign('offer_id')->references('id')->on('offers')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('restrict');
    });
```

Im adding 2 foreign keys both have onUpdate and onDelete constraints but only the update constraint gets added.

If i delete the onUpdate, it will correctly add the onDelete constraint.

I cannot add them separately because i get the error of duplicate key.

I could add them manually with a raw sql statement but if theres a right way to do it id rather do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, if you set the columns as `nullable()`, Laravel sets the foreign keys correctly.

That said, I can see that causing other problems, so I recommend doing the raw SQL statement.